# How do I apply a function to binomial function in R in matrix

Tags: r, matrix, layer, sapply

I am new to R and am struggling with layering functions in R for a matrix.
I have applied a binomial to an empty matrix as below:

```
prevalence <- 0.01
A <- sapply(1:10 ,function(p) rbinom(50,1,prevalence))
```

Now I need to add the following distribution to all the 1s in matrix A:

```
B <- extraDistr::rtpois(35000, 1.93, 1, 8)
```

How do I do that? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can just replace the indices you need. Here's an example.

```
prevalence <- 0.01

A <- sapply(1:10 ,function(p) rbinom(50,1,prevalence))
B <- A 
B[B == 1] = extraDistr::rtpois(sum(A), 1.93, 1, 8)
```

But I note that you're not using p at all in the function, so why not use replicate?

```
B = A = replicate(10, rbinom(50,1,prevalence))
B[B == 1] = extraDistr::rtpois(sum(A), 1.93, 1, 8)
```

results in

```
B
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [2,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [5,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [7,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [8,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [9,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[10,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[11,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[12,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[13,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[14,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[15,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[16,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[17,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[18,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[19,]    0    0    0    0    0    4    0    0    0     0
[20,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[21,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[22,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[23,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[24,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[25,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[26,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     3
[27,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[28,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[29,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[30,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[31,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[32,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[33,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[34,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[35,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[36,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[37,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[38,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[39,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[40,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[41,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[42,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[43,]    0    4    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[44,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[45,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[46,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[47,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[48,]    0    0    0    4    0    0    0    0    0     0
[49,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[50,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the 35000 is a mistake, since (1) the number of `1`s in `A` cannot be known a priori, and (2) the size of A (50x10) precludes having 35000 of anything.

I suspect you are intending to replace all `1`s in `A` with something else, where "something else" is from another random distribution.

I'll use `sample` as the replacement distribution since I don't have `extraDistr` available:

```r
set.seed(2023)
A <- sapply(1:10 ,function(p) rbinom(50,1,prevalence))
which(A == 1, arr.ind = TRUE)
#      row col
# [1,]  14   1
# [2,]   9   2
# [3,]  43   2
# [4,]  35   5
# [5,]  13   6
# [6,]   3   7
# [7,]   7   9
A[A == 1] <- sample(2:100, size = sum(A == 1), replace = TRUE)
A
#       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#  [1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
#  [2,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
#  [3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0   60    0    0     0
#  [4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
#  [5,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
#  [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
#  [7,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   98     0
#  [8,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
#  [9,]    0    7    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [10,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [11,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [12,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [13,]    0    0    0    0    0   22    0    0    0     0
# [14,]   62    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [15,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [16,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [17,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [18,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [19,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [20,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [21,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [22,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [23,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [24,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [25,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [26,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [27,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [28,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [29,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [30,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [31,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [32,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [33,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [34,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [35,]    0    0    0    0   74    0    0    0    0     0
# [36,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [37,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [38,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [39,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [40,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [41,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [42,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [43,]    0    2    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [44,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [45,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [46,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [47,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [48,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [49,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [50,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
```

Takeaways:

- for SA only, I show that `which(A == 1, arr.ind=TRUE)` tells us there are 7 `1`s in the matrix, in those row/col positions; this step is not required for the replacement;
- `A[A == 1] <- ...` will replace only those instances
- use `sum(A == 1)` as the `n=` in your function, as in `A[A == 1] <- rtpois(sum(A == 1), 1.93, 1, 8)` (my use of `sample`, `2:100`, and `replace=TRUE` are purely demonstrative, they don't matter to you)